# DocuSign PHP SDK - Why Are Two E-Mails Send Out When I Call createEnvelope()?

Tags: php, docusignapi

I use the following code - based off of the official DocuSign PHP SDK readme - to send an e-mail with my document:

```
// assign recipient to template role by setting name, email, and role name.  Note that the
// template role name must match the placeholder role name saved in your account template.
$templateRole = new  DocuSign\eSign\Model\TemplateRole();
$templateRole->setEmail('myemail@gmail.com');
$templateRole->setName('sally');
$templateRole->setRoleName('test');
$templateRole->setTabs($tabs);

// instantiate a new envelope object and configure settings
$envelop_definition = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeDefinition();
$envelop_definition->setEmailSubject("Subject Subject");
$envelop_definition->setEmailBlurb("Dear Sarah, I love u");
$envelop_definition->setTemplateId("a7d49esa-c908-432f-a8fa-3sawa25eff13");
$envelop_definition->setTemplateRoles(array($templateRole));

// set envelope status to "sent" to immediately send the signature request
$envelop_definition->setStatus("sent");

// optional envelope parameters
$options = new \DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi\CreateEnvelopeOptions();
$options->setCdseMode(null);
$options->setMergeRolesOnDraft(null);

// create and send the envelope (aka signature request)
$envelop_summary = $envelopeApi->createEnvelope($accountId, $envelop_definition, $options);
if(!empty($envelop_summary)){
    echo "$envelop_summary";
}
```

The above sends out two e-mails with identifical subject and body, but which link to different DocuSign URLs.  One of the URLs the emails link to has filled in fields (name, address, etc..) while the other does not.

If I comment out the `createEnvelope()` call then neither e-mail is sent out.

Why is the above snippet sending out two e-mails when it is called?

Comment: Please use the DocuSign [logging](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging) feature to post your request and error response. Of course, omit private info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through my sent logs dashboard and noticed that while I received two e-mails for every send request I made, there was only one sent record for each of the requests.  I am assuming that the Sandbox environment sends out a CC on purpose to the TO address when you hit the send endpoint.

Comment: This answer is not true. CC recipients are only created if the envelope asks for them directly or via a template. You mean that the certificate of completion shows both a signer and cc recipient? That will only happen if the envelope requests a CC recipient.

Comment: @LarryK I think you should do more homework and talk to your dev team here.  This is what is happening and there's obviously some disconnect between what you know and what is actually implemented that someone in your position (as support on SO for DocuSign) should investigate.  I have had two questions related to the PHP SDK on here in the last week and the "answers" you have posted on both aren't answers at all, but rather links to code samples which don't work.  You also don't seem to want to go into specifics when pressed for details.

Comment: @LarryK Also, regarding your comment that `Your code looks ok, but not great` in your answer.  The code I posted above is a copy and paste of the sample given in the official DocuSign PHP SDK.  I went through the sample code you've linked everywhere and it does exactly the same thing as the code from the official readme.  The only difference being the official readme sets options using class methods while your code sets options using a global array.  The response JSON from the API is the same.  To be honest, I think your colleague's `ok, but not great` code looks a lot better than your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks ok, but not great:

- No need to set the envelope cdse and merge role options if you're just using a stored server-side template.
- You're setting the role's tabs element but this isn't usually needed and (your snippet) has not set the $tabs variable.

**I suggest** that you check out the DocuSign [PHP code examples and launcher](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-php-auth-code-grant). It includes examples that use a server side template both for the simple case and with an additional document added at envelope create time.